# Trouble using mattgodbolt agner test programs

Tags: x86, cpu, intel, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

My goal is to regenerate results of BTB test reported in http://xania.org/201602/bpu-part-three article.

I have cloned the https://github.com/mattgodbolt/agner repository. Looking at the `agner/src/PMCTest.txt` instruction for linux, I can't find `DriverSrcLinux.zip` file in the repository.  I just used make command in the agner/src/driver folder then, hope it installed the required drivers.

Been able to make the https://github.com/mattgodbolt/agner/tree/master/src src files.

one binary file will be generated at /src/out/ folder but it is not executable. Any idea how that works?

There is one btb_size file under test/ folder. It needs to import Agner.py file in the lib folder which I just copied to the same directory for it to find. I don't know how to run it or if it needs to be added to PMCTestB64.nasm file, how I'm supposed to do that. (In the instruction file, it is said that I have to insert the code in the 'Test code start' section of the ' PMCTestB64.nasm' file. But it is not clear how to do that.)

The instruction looks very complicated and a lot of files are missing for instance I can't find a64.sh. ( or I have to generate them which I don't know how).

I'd like to mainly run the BTB size test program and monitor the  `e6:1f` counter on my Intel Haswell processor with Ubuntu 14.04. 
Any simpler instruction containing the missing files?

Comment: I didn't read your whole post, but a lot of mentioned files are in the official [Test programs zip](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp).

Comment: That correct! Thanks, I got them. But still struggling a lot to understand how this works.